# How can I make a shell.nix that runs some code, only using inbuilt derivation function?

Tags: nix, nixos

I basically want to create my own simple version of `mkShell`, so now I'm trying to understand how it would even be possible to execute some code before the shell actually pops up. I googled for a bit, and came up with this:

```hs
let pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}; in
derivation {
  name = "hello";

  shellHook = ''
    echo "hello world!"
  '';

  system = builtins.currentSystem;

  builder = "${pkgs.bash}/bin/bash";
  args = [ ./setup.sh ];
}
```

...where `setup.sh` contains `echo "hello" > $out`.

From nix-shell documentation:

> If the derivation defines the variable shellHook, it will be run after $stdenv/setup has been sourced. Since this hook is not executed by regular Nix builds, it allows you to perform initialisation specific to nix-shell. For example, the derivation attribute

```hs
shellHook =
  ''
    echo "Hello shell"
    export SOME_API_TOKEN="$(cat ~/.config/some-app/api-token)"
  '';
```

But that doesn't output anything, although if I replace `derivation {}` with `pkgs.mkShell {}`, then it does. How can I make this behaviour work without actually using `pkgs.mkShell`?

Answer (score 2):

The question got answered on the NixOS forum.

So, now I know that I have to override stdenv to run make this work.

`nix-shell` sources the `$stdenv/setup` script. And then before shells open runs `runHook shellHook`, so `runHook` function can also be defined in that `$stdenv/setup` script.

So if I

1. make a `myStdEnv/setup` file and put there for example `echo "hello world"`
2. pass `stdenv = ./myStdenv;` in the `derivation{}`

Then it will be enough to output "hello world" when I run `nix-shell`.

Complete code:

`shell.nix`

```
let pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}; in
derivation {
  name = "hello";

  system = builtins.currentSystem;

  builder = "${pkgs.bash}/bin/bash";
  args = [ ./setup.sh ];

  stdenv = ./myStdEnv;
}
```

`myStdEnv/setup`

```
echo "hello world"
```

(This is enough for me to understand what I wanted to understand, but I suppose it would be good to also add a `runHook` function there)

Answer (score 0):

One means to avoid this issue is to use the newer replacement for `nix-shell`, `nix develop`, to invoke a flake devShell. As a working example, after creating the following `flake.nix`:

```hs
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };
  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }: flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
    let
      pkgs = import nixpkgs { inherit system; };
    in {
    devShells = {
      exampleDevShell = derivation {
        inherit system;
        name = "so-question-77656854";
        builder = "${pkgs.bash}/bin/bash";
        args = [ "-c" ''touch "$out"'' ];
        outputs = [ "out" ];
        shellHook = ''
          echo "Hello, world"
        '';
      };
    };
  });
}
```

...running `nix develop .#exampleDevShell` prints `Hello, world` to stdout.

Comment: I'm only talking about a regular `shell.nix`, and not flakes yet :(
Did running `nix shell` on my file give you an output?

Comment: Sorry -- I stopped thinking about the pre-flake world years ago, and have no interest in going back to it or digging up its codepaths.

Comment: @Wynell Read this answer as "one solution to this problem is to switch to flakes".

Comment: Okay, thanks! By the way, I've found the answer (and I'm going to post it here now)